# Is there a way to express the CSS3 negation pseudo-class in CSS2?

Tags: css

For example, I have some CSS3 code:

```
.iMore:not (.__lod ):active {
    color: #fff
}

.iMore.__lod {
    color: #888
}
```

I need to somehow express the same thing in CSS2.  I figure it would have to be more verbose, but is it even possible?

Comment: You don't need a space after `not` and before your parenthesis. Just FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible. The best you can hope for is to set a default style (`.iMore`), and some sort of "active" style (`.__lod`). Removing the active style class will "disable" the element.

The problem with CSS2 is that it was never originally meant as a language to perform logic operations as CSS3 lets you do. Instead, it was designed to take what *was there* and--without much computation--style it based on those directives. Basically, as classes/IDs/etc are added, CSS2 lets you add on descriptors. CSS3 introduces some logic and computational structures (`nth-child`, anybody?), so it's technically not fully reversible.